# Intellij idea ultimate not connecting to Visual Studio Online

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs, azure-devops

I'm getting the following error when connecting to visual studio online with tfs plugin:

```
org.apache.axis2.databinding.AFBException: Unexpected subelement InheritLevel
```

It seems like it does connect to VSO and this problem occurs when its loading the project information. I'm using the alternate connection method, which is already enabled on VSO. How can I fix this problem or do I have to switch to eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IntelliJ plugin for TFS is based on the 2010 api and is not well supported. As TFS and VS 2010 are now no longer supported I would expect breakages. Other than putting pressure on JetBrains to fix it you can:

1. use Eclipse that has fully supported first part plugin
2. Use the command line out side of IntelliJ

Nether will be what you want, but it may be the best that you can get without Jet Brains fixing it.